# I want movie name from the given database

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Performance table:

```
   PerformanceId    SingerId    MovieId     NumberofSongs


   1                1           1           2
   2                3           1           4
   3                2           2           6
   4                4           5           3
   5                5           5           3
   6                2           6           2
   7                4           6           5
   8                6           4           6
   9                6           3           3
   10               4           3           4
```

Singer table:

```
    SingerId    SingerName    City           DOB          Gender

    1           A             Hyderabad      14-Apr-65    M
    2           B             Chennai        25-May-84    M
    3           C             Bangalore      14-Sep-78    F
    4           D             Hyderabad      17-Jan-70    M
    5           E             Hyderabad      18-Mar-87    F
    6           F             Bangalore      23-Aug-75    F
```

Movie table:

```
    MovieId     MovieName      ReleaseDate

    1           AAA            12-Jan-15
    2           BBB            19-Sep-12
    3           CCC            23-Jul-10
    4           DDD            06-Oct-01
    5           EEE            08-Nov-05
    6           FFF            18-Apr-99
    7           GGG            07-Aug-12
```

I would need to list the MovieId, MovieName in which both Male and Female singers are performed
(list the movieid, moviename  in which male and femail singer ie both singer are performed in one movie)

Hi guys please help me out with this query i tried i am not getting exact query

Here's my query:

```
   select * from movies a inner join performance b 
   on  a.movie_id=b.movie_id where b.singer_id in 
  (select singer_id from singer where  gender = 'F') c inner join
  (SELECT SINGER_ID FROM SINGER WHERE gender = 'M') d
  on c.singer_id=d.singer_id;
```

Comment: thank you sujania please help me

Comment: please reformat your question: it's hard to understand your need.

Comment: list the movieid, moviename  in which male and femail singer ie both singer are performed in one movie

Comment: ok I got it. I've edited your question and added an answer working for me.

Answer (score 1):

First create a view "MOVIE_ANALYSIS" where you'll have a list of all movies and if they've mixed singers or not:

```
CREATE VIEW MOVIE_ANALYSIS AS SELECT
  M.MOVIEID ,
  M.MOVIENAME, 
  (COUNT(DISTINCT S.GENDER) > 1) AS MIXED
FROM MOVIE M
INNER JOIN PERFORMANCE P ON P.MOVIEID = M.MOVIEID 
INNER JOIN SINGER S ON S.SINGERID  = P.SINGERID
GROUP BY M.MOVIEID ;
```

Then you'll get your final result with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIE_ANALYSIS WHERE MIXED IS TRUE ;
```

The reason I used an intermediate view is that in several SQL engines, you cannot use the computed "mixed" attribute directly in the same query with a group by. It'll keep insisting that mixed column is missing.

Validated and test on H2. I did not test on Oracle, as I've no access to it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is the INTERSECT statement (using Oracle):

```
select movieId
  from performance a
 where exists (select 1 
                 from singer b 
                where A.singerID = b.singerID 
                  and b.gender = 'F')
intersect 
select movieId
  from performance a
 where exists (select 1 
                 from singer b 
                where A.singerID = b.singerID 
                  and b.gender = 'M');
```

Then you just join the movie IDs you get back to the Movie table.

INTERSECT will only bring back IDs that are common to both queries (or however many you use).

Comment: So another extra sql query is needed to complete the answer. Could you please add it ? For comparison sake. Good use of intersect. Wondering if this would scale or not.